# Javascript string validation with cookies

Tags: javascript, string, validation, cookies

I started by setting some cookies on my website, the cookie captures the name of the user and displays greetings messages. It was created using guides from w3schools. It worked fine. However, when I try to perform the following String Validation for a test, the cookies magically stop working - no name capture, no greetings messages. The validation also doesn't work and never has. Why? Help? Need some code to make this work:

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var title = cname + "=";
    var cookie_array = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<cookie_array.length; i++) {
        var check = cookie_array[i];
        while (check.charAt(0)==' ') check = check.substring(1);
        if (check.indexOf(title) != -1) {
            return check.substring(title.length, check.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var name=getCookie("name");
    if (name != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + name);
    } else {
       name = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (name != null && name != "") {
           setCookie("name", name, 30);
       }
    }
}

function RemoveC() {

document.cookie = "name=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
 }
function Test(str) {

return /^[a-zA-Z()]+$/.test(str)

}


function Validation() {
document.getElementById("vresult").innerHTML = "";
PetName = prompt("Please enter your favourite pet's name:","");
var T = Test(PetName);
if (T == false) { document.getElementById("vresult").innerHTML = "You did not enter a valid     name!"; }
else { document.getElementById("vresult").innerHTML = PetName + " is a lovely name, good     choice!!"; }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, this is strange but, I've been trying to get this to work for the past two days now and I just went back to my website tab and refreshed and everything worked for the first time. Weird, why is that?